# Extract classes from MNIST dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, mnist

I am working with the MNIST dataset and I am exploring the data to plot them, but I am stuck with a problem when trying to extract the different classes from the dataset.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=False)

dataWithLabels = zip(mnist.train.labels, mnist.train.images)

digitDict = {}

for i in range(0,10):
    digitDict[i] = []

for i in dataWithLabels:
    digitDict[i[0][0]].append(i[1])

for i in range(0,10):
    digitDict[i] = np.matrix(digitDict[i])
    print("Digit {0} matrix shape: {1}".format(i,digitDict[i].shape))
```

The output is:

```py
Digit 0 matrix shape: (49556, 784)
Digit 1 matrix shape: (5444, 784)
Digit 2 matrix shape: (1, 0)
Digit 3 matrix shape: (1, 0)
Digit 4 matrix shape: (1, 0)
Digit 5 matrix shape: (1, 0)
Digit 6 matrix shape: (1, 0)
Digit 7 matrix shape: (1, 0)
Digit 8 matrix shape: (1, 0)
Digit 9 matrix shape: (1, 0)
```

But it should be:

```py
Digit 0 matrix shape: (5444, 784)
Digit 1 matrix shape: (6179, 784)
Digit 2 matrix shape: (5470, 784)
Digit 3 matrix shape: (5638, 784)
Digit 4 matrix shape: (5307, 784)
Digit 5 matrix shape: (4987, 784)
Digit 6 matrix shape: (5417, 784)
Digit 7 matrix shape: (5715, 784)
Digit 8 matrix shape: (5389, 784)
Digit 9 matrix shape: (5454, 784)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your output (the code throws an error for me), but you can get this much simpler:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=False)

digitDict = {}

for i in range(10):
    mask = (mnist.train.labels == i)
    digitDict[i] = mnist.train.images[mask]

for i in range(10):
    print("Digit {0} matrix shape: {1}".format(i,digitDict[i].shape))
```

This should be much more efficient than your version. `mnist.train.labels == i` gives a boolean array showing you which entries of the array are equal to `i`, then we use that to get the corresponding images.